# In React, how to have a dynamic variable name in a condition statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    {this.props.fields.map(field => (
      <div key={field.skill_id}>

        <label key={field.skill_id} className={( (this.props.formState && this.props.formState.skill_id_1) === String(field.skill_id) ? "active": "" ) + " X"}>
```

Right now I have the above hard coded with `this.props.formState.skill_id_1` ... specifically `skill_id_1`

I need `skill_id_1` to be dynamic, where it's `skill_id_` + field.skill_id from the mapping above.

How can I make the condition dynamic so it becomes:

this.props.formState.skill_id_#####

where ##### is dynamically assigned from the .map above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an iterator with the map function.

```
arr.map((field, i) => <div className={`skill-${i}`}>{field}</div>)
```